# what is wrong with the following typecasting c code

Tags: c, casting, syntax-error, variable-assignment

I have this code

```
if (hashtable_count(h) > 0)
    {
      do {
          kk = (key*)hashtable_iterator_key(itr);
          v =(value*) hashtable_iterator_value(itr);
....
```

key and value are both declared in the same code block as

```
 struct key *k, *kk;
struct value *v;
```

and VC 2010 reports the following error

error C2065: 'key' : undeclared identifier

error C2059: syntax error : ')'

error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier

error C2059: syntax error : ')'

the errors are for the two assignment lines. Two first errors are for the first assignment statement and the next  for the last one.

I will be happy to give more details if neccessary.

More information:
Here are the two functions

```
 void * hashtable_iterator_key(struct hashtable_itr *i)
  { return i->e->k; }

void * hashtable_iterator_value(struct hashtable_itr *i)
  { return i->e->v; }
```

If I don't type cast the returned value to key*, it reports type mismatch error

Comment: Please supply a complete, yet small, example.

Comment: Missed including the header where `key` and `value` are typedef'ed?

Comment: C != C++. In C++ a `struct xyz {...};` automatically generates the typedef for "xyz". In C it does not; you still have to type `struct xyz abc = {...}`. Also: remove the casts; they are not needed :void pointers can be cast to any pointer type. (and the casts are ugly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(key*) in you cast should be (struct key*)

You have not created the the type "key".

i.e. you have not done:

```
typedef struct
{
   <some defines>
} key;
```

Then (key*) would work.

Answer (score 1):

`struct key *, value*;` does not declare anything. It's not even valid C.

If you want to do a forward declaration, the syntax is this:

```
struct key;
struct value;
```

However, are you sure that you aren't supposed to replace `key` and `value` with some custom type? Often datastructures in C have `void *` for fields like that so you can put any pointer in them and then cast them to your own structures.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the compiler doesn't know about the "key" and "value" type. Are you sure you made the right includes ?